# Is there a mapping from Stack Overflow tags to Wikipedia/Wikidata entities?

Tags: discussion, tags

For most popular tags, it would seem that there is a single obvious Wikipedia article or section of an article that could represent it.  In the spirit of [linked data](http://linkeddata.org/), it would make sense to have a mapping from Stack Overflow tags to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org) or [Wikidata](http://www.wikidata.org) entities.

For example, the top 10 tags unambiguously map to:

```
Tag           | Wikipedia article                | Wikidata entity
------------- | -------------------------------- | ---------------
java          | Java_(programming_language)      | Q251
c#            | C_Sharp_(programming_language)   | Q2370
javascript    | JavaScript                       | Q2005
php           | PHP                              | Q59
android       | Android_(operating_system)       | Q94
jquery        | jQuery                           | Q230036
python        | Python_(programming_language)    | Q28865
html          | HTML                             | Q8811
c++           | C++                              | Q2407
mysql         | MySQL                            | Q850
```

Does a mapping for at least the the few thousand most popular tags exist already in a manner that is easy to access programmatically?  If it doesn't yet exist but people see the need, should it be a part of Stack Overflow itself, or should it be hosted externally? Would it make sense to build a similar mapping for other sites in the Stack Exchange network?

**Potential applications**:

- Automatically constructing lists of tags related by certain properties (ex. functional languages, operating systems, etc.) derived from Wikidata/Wikipedia properties/categories
- Suggesting tags for questions based on the text similarity to Wikipedia articles, or based on explicit links to Wikipedia in the question
- If this is done with other Stack Exchange sites, automatically linking to corresponding tags on different sites, without relying on constructing a mesh of inter-site links or enforcing the same tag names (ex., there is a "statistics" tag on stackoverflow, datascience.se, math.se, and physics.se, but mathoverflow and cstheory.se call the same concept "st.statistics")

Comment: What do you plan to do with such a mapping?  That will determine whether anyone bothers to compile one.

Comment: I would think it would be generically useful, but my immediate need is I want to categorize tags based on Wikidata properties/Wikipedia categories; for example, [this automatically generated list](http://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-todo/autolist.html?q=CLAIM%5B31%3A9143%5D) has all the things Wikidata knows are programming languages.  Another cool use is that you could automatically translate tag names into other languages.

Comment: This might also get some needed overhauling on the ECMAScript articles that are sorely out of date (and I don't have the time to make the full re-writes).

Comment: It would make sense to build a mapping system if there was a use for the data that it gathers. Taking a looking at the [data for Java](http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q251), I can see its developer, what its named after, and other information. What I can't see is how this data can be useful **in improving stackoverflow**. Can you elaborate the ways in which the data can be Incorporated into StackOverflow? Like, are you suggesting that this data could be used to improve the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)?

Comment: This website is for professionals and enthusiasts, I don't see what an established programmer would gain from reading a wikipedia entry rather than the correct documentation (which from the tags I have seen is normally linked)

Comment: That would be a great question for http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DaveChen:  Having this data would let you use category information from Wikipedia/Wikidata and apply it to browsing and grouping tags.  For example, it would be nice, if you cared about functional programming, to look at all questions for all languages that are [in the "functional languages" category on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Functional_languages), rather than relying on every one of them having the "functional-programming" tag.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Great idea!  I will post it there.

Comment: @bskaggs So you're proposing that tags on Stackoverflow be grouped? It's an interesting idea, but most people have a set of tags that they are comfortable with, so adding a system to group tags doesn't seem necessary. Can you provide some examples within your question on how this data can be applied to SO?

Comment: @DaveChen: I edited the question with some example applications.

Comment: Such a mapping would help in text annotation, tag translation, suggestions. This idea is good! It could be useful on both sides, SO and WP.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Final Update** (16 October 2014):  [Property P1482](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1482) on WikiData now contains these links for more than 1700 entities.  If there is something missing, add it on WikiData!

**Original Answer**:
I started building [a Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SGojZbwgJTxKrihGbeNLO502Tj3zvmzIiPv_ECK8494/edit?usp=sharing) with the list of all tags used at least once.  Anyone can edit it and add new links to Wikipedia.

**Edit**: Getting sick of manual labor, I went through the May 2014 dump and pulled out any links to Wikipedia.  I then used the Wikipedia API to normalize names and follow redirects.  I've got the [results as a gist](https://gist.github.com/bskaggs/bdb51d660001f332d7dd) on Github.  I will merge these into the above spreadsheet.

**Edit 2**: Following some suggestions on the Open Data Stack Exchange site, and after some discussion on WikiData, I've proposed "Stack Exchange tag" [as a new property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Property_proposal/Authority_control#Stack_Exchange_tag), so hopefully we will be able to soon store the data on WikiData itself.

**Edit 3** (23 September 2014): Success!  [Property P1482](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1482) was created on WikiData to hold "Stack Exchange tag" URLs.  I will be uploading what I currently have soon.

**Edit 4** (25 September 2014): I [created a bot](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/User:StackerBot) on WikiData, and am seeking permission there to do the upload in bulk.  In the meantime, I asked a [question over at meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240056/can-i-re-publish-links-extracted-from-stack-exchange-data-dumps-under-the-public) to see if I can publish the extracted information under the [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) license that WikiData uses.

Comment: Because of "the spirit of linked data", you might want to use [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About) instead of Wikipedia.

Comment: @unor: Since most of the popular tags have Wikipedia links, and many link to subsections of articles, it's easiest for me to use Wikipedia as my anchor.  But, after that, it should be easy to pull through to DBpedia via Wikipedia.